# How to adjust the size of the points when using plotKML in R

Tags: r, kml

I would like to use the `plotKML` package to display a SpatialPointsDataFrame object in GoogleEarth.  When I just pass the `sp` object that I want to plot, it works fine, but tries to guess what I want the color and size of the icons to be.  When I look at the documentation for `plotKML` it specifies that if the S4 signiture is a SpatialPointsDataFrame then I can pass a value for the colour, and size.  However every time I try this I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(obj@data, , deparse(size)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

The following is an example code block that will reproduce this error.

```
library(sp)
library(plotKML)

data(bigfoot) 

bigfoot = head(bigfoot)

coordinates(bigfoot) <- c('Lon','Lat') 
proj4string(bigfoot) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") 

plotKML(bigfoot, size = 1)
```

As an aside, I took a look at the source code and thought that might help.  The relevant code chunk in the source (plotKML.sp.R) is the following:

```
  # Guess aesthetics if missing:
  if(missing(size)){ 
    obj@data[,"size"] <- obj@data[,1]
  } else {
    if(is.name(size)|is.call(size)){
      obj@data[,"size"] <- eval(size, obj@data)
    } else {
      obj@data[,"size"] <- obj@data[,deparse(size)]      
    }
  }
  if(missing(colour)){ 
    obj@data[,"colour"] <- obj@data[,1] 
    message("Plotting the first variable on the list")  
  } else {
    if(is.name(colour)|is.call(colour)){
      obj@data[,"colour"] <- eval(colour, obj@data)
    } else {
      obj@data[,"colour"] <- obj@data[,as.character(colour)]      
    }
  }
```

Please help, I for the life of me can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment you can use the [kml function](http://plotkml.r-forge.r-project.org/kml.html) to modify aesthetics parameters e.g.:

```
data(eberg)
eberg <- eberg[runif(nrow(eberg))<.1,]
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
coordinates(eberg) <- ~X+Y
proj4string(eberg) <- CRS("+init=epsg:31467")
## Not run: # Simple plot
kml(eberg, file = "eberg-0.kml")
# Plot using aesthetics
kml(eberg, colour = SNDMHT_A, size = CLYMHT_A, alpha = 0.75, file = "eberg-1.kml")
```

I need to take a look to see why 'plotKML' method does not pass further the 'size' argument. Instead of using plotKML, I often recommend to the package users to start building their own visualization templates/functions e.g.:

```
kml_points <- function(obj, file, z.lim, points_names="", ...){  
  kml_open(file)
  kml_layer(obj, colour=obj at data[,1], shape="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon18.png", 
colour_scale=SAGA_pal[[1]], points_names="", ...)
  kml_legend.bar(x=obj at data[,1], legend.file=gsub(".kml", ".png", 
file), legend.pal=SAGA_pal[[1]], z.lim=z.lim)
  kml_screen(image.file=gsub(".kml", ".png", file))
  kml_close(file)
  kml_View(file)
}
```

PS: If you plan to write large stack of points, please consider also using the [klm.tiles](http://plotkml.r-forge.r-project.org/kml.tiles.html) function.

Answer (score 2):

The source code you posted suggests a solution. First append a new numeric variable to the spatialpointsdataframe. Then use that as your size argument, but apply 'as.name' first:

```
n <- nrow(bigfoot@data) 
bigfoot$newsize <- rep(1, n) 
head(bigfoot) 
plotKML(bigfoot, file.name='big.kml', size=as.name('newsize'))
```

Comment: When I tried this with two sizes, e.g., 1 and 2, the sizes were not proportionally correct - size = 2 were HUGE and size = 1 were tiny.